# How to dynamically add row and calculate sum using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add rows dynamically to a html table to generate a bill using jquery. I want to calculate the grand total dynamically as the rows are added or removed

My code

These are my input fields from which the values are taken. All the DropDown boxes are populated from DB.

```
<div class="block-fluid">                        

                        <div class="row-form clearfix">
                            <div class="span3">Select Product:</div>
                            <div class="span7">
                                <select name="selectprod" id="s2_2" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <option value="0">Choose a Product...</option>
                                   <optgroup id="Tablets" label="Tablets">

                                   </optgroup>
                                   <optgroup id="Capsule" label="Capsule">

                                   </optgroup>
                                   <optgroup id="Syrup" label="Syrup">

                                   </optgroup> 
                                   <optgroup id="Drops" label="Drops">

                                   </optgroup>
                                   <optgroup id="Inhalers" label="Inhalers">

                                   </optgroup>
                                   <optgroup id="Topical" label="Topical">

                                   </optgroup>
                                   <optgroup id="Intravascular" label="Intravascular">

                                   </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>           
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="prodnamediv">
                             <div class="span3">Product Name:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="prodnameinput" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="prodcompdiv">
                             <div class="span3">Product Company:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="prodcompinput" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="prodtypediv">
                             <div class="span3">Product Type:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="prodtypeinput" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="proddosediv">
                             <div class="span3">Product Dose:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="proddoseinput" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="tabletdiv">
                             <div class="span3">Tablets Per Strip:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="tabletinput" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="prodcapacitydiv">
                             <div class="span3">Product Capacity:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="prodcapacityinput" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="currentstockdiv">
                             <div class="span3">Current Stock Quantity:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="currentstockinput" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="prodpricetabcapdiv">
                             <div class="span3">Price Per Tablet/Capsule:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="prodpricetabcapinput" type="text" value="" />
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="prodpricediv">
                             <div class="span3">Product Price:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="prodpriceinput" type="text" value="" />
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="qtytoselldiv">
                             <div class="span3">No. of Quantities to sell:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="qtytosellinput" type="text" value="" />
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="tablettoselldiv">
                             <div class="span3">No. of Tablets/Capsules to sell:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="tablettosellinput" type="text" value="" />
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="pkgdatediv">
                             <div class="span3">Packaging Date:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="pkgdateinput" type="text" value="" />
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="manufactdiv">
                             <div class="span3">Manufacturing Date:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="manufactinput" type="text" value="" />
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="expdatediv">
                             <div class="span3">Expiry Date:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                             <input id="expdateinput" type="text" value="" />
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-form clearfix" id="batchnodiv">
                             <div class="span3">Batch No.:</div>
                             <div class="span7">
                                <select name="select" id="s2_1" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <option value="0">choose a option...</option>                             
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="toolbar clearfix">
                            <div class="right">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                     <button class="btn" id="addtopurchase" type="button" value="Add"><span>Add</span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
```

This is my table which is populated dynamically when above "Add" button is pressed

```
<div class="block-fluid table-sorting clearfix">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table" id="tSortable_2">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="20%">Product</th>
                                    <th width="12%">Pkg Date</th>
                                    <th width="12%">Mfact date</th>
                                    <th width="12%">Expiry</th>
                                    <th width="12%">Batch No.</th>
                                    <th width="12%">Unit Price</th>
                                    <th width="10%">Qty</th>
                                    <th width="10%">Subtotal</th>  
                                    <th></th>                                  
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tablebody">
                               <tr>
                         <td class="prodname">prod</td>
                         <td class="pkgdate">pkgdate</td>
                         <td class="manufactdate">manufactdate</td>
                         <td class="expdate">expdate</td>
                         <td class="batchno">batchno</td>
                         <td class="unitprice">pertabprice</td>
                         <td class="qty">qty</td>
                         <td class="subtot">subtotal</td>
                         <td>
                            '<button class="btn btn-link" type="button">Remove</button>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>   
                                    <td></td> 
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Total:</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                  <div class="toolbar clear clearfix">
                            <div class="center">                                
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-warning"><span class="icon-ok icon-white"></span></button>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

This script populates the above table rows dynamically

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#addtopurchase').click(function(e){
         alert('Clicked');
         var selected = $('#s2_2 :selected');
         var type = selected.parent().attr('label');
         var prod = $('#s2_2 option:selected').text();
         if(prod != "Choose a Product...")
             {
             alert('In prod');

             if(type == "Tablets" || type == "Capsule")
                 {
                 alert('In tablets');
                 var stock = Number($('#currentstockinput').val());
                 var qty = Number($('#tablettosellinput').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
                 if(qty < stock)
                 {
                 var pertabprice = Number($('#prodpricetabcapinput').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")).toFixed(2);
                 var subtotal = qty * pertabprice;
                 var pkgdate = $('#pkgdateinput').val();
                 var manufactdate = $('#manufactinput').val();
                 var expdate = $('#expdateinput').val();
                 var batchno = $('#s2_1 option:selected').text();

                 $('#tablebody').prepend('<tr>'+
                         '<td class="prodname">'+prod+'</td>'+
                         '<td class="pkgdate">'+pkgdate+'</td>'+
                         '<td class="manufactdate">'+manufactdate+'</td>'+   
                         '<td class="expdate">'+expdate+'</td>'+ 
                         '<td class="batchno">'+batchno+'</td>'+
                         '<td class="unitprice">'+pertabprice+'</td>'+
                         '<td class="qty">'+qty+'</td>'+
                         '<td class="subtot">'+subtotal+'</td>'+
                         '<td>'+
                            '<button class="btn btn-link" type="button">Remove</button>'+
                        '</td>'+
                     '</tr>');

                 }
                 else
                     {
                     alert('Not enough Stock');
                     }
                 loadgrandtotal();
                 }
             else
                 {

                 var stock = Number($('#currentstockinput').val());
                 var qty = Number($('#qtytosellinput').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
                 if(qty < stock)
                 {

                 var prodprice = Number($('#prodpriceinput').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")).toFixed(2);

                 var subtotal = qty * prodprice;

                 var pkgdate = $('#pkgdateinput').val();

                 var manufactdate = $('#manufactinput').val();

                 var expdate = $('#expdateinput').val();

                 var batchno = $('#s2_1 option:selected').text();

                 $('#tablebody').prepend('<tr>'+
                         '<td class="prodname">'+prod+'</td>'+
                         '<td class="pkgdate">'+pkgdate+'</td>'+
                         '<td class="manufactdate">'+manufactdate+'</td>'+   
                         '<td class="expdate">'+expdate+'</td>'+ 
                         '<td class="batchno">'+batchno+'</td>'+
                         '<td class="unitprice">'+prodprice+'</td>'+
                         '<td class="qty">'+qty+'</td>'+
                         '<td class="subtot">'+subtotal+'</td>'+
                         '<td>'+
                            '<button class="btn btn-link" type="button">Remove</button>'+
                        '</td>'+
                     '</tr>');

                 }
                 else
                     {
                     alert('Not enough Stock');
                     }
                 }
             loadgrandtotal();
             }
         else
             {

             }

     })

    });
    </script>
```

Here is the problem. This script should calculate all the subtotals and generate Grand Total
But this script doesn't seem to work and I am not able to figure out why. The td values are read from class ".subtot" which is associated with a td and is generated dynamically using above script

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function loadgrandtotal()
         {
var sum=0;
var prodprice = 0;
             $('#tSortable_2 tbody tr').each(function() {
                var prodprice = Number($(this).find(".subtot").text()).toFixed(2);  
                sum = sum + prodprice;
             });

         }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do your loop directly on the `subtot` class.

You also need to ensure you don't call `toFixed` before you add it to the `sum`, because that will cause a string concatenation. Do it at the end instead, like this:

```
function loadgrandtotal() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.subtot').each(function () {
        var prodprice = Number($(this).text());
        sum = sum + prodprice;
    });
    $("#total").text(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bj4nq698/)

Answer (score 0):

you should not itereate over the elements to calculate the sum, instead use an Object to hold and render your purchased data. i have provided you with a sample code that you can run to get the hang of things

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

function PurchaseTable(elementId){

this.containerElement = $('#' + elementId);
this.purchasedItems = [];
this.totalAmount = 0;

this._initializeTableLayout();

}

PurchaseTable.prototype.addItem = function(purchasedItem){
this.purchasedItems.push(purchasedItem);    
this.totalAmount += purchasedItem.subTotal;
this._addtoTable(purchasedItem);
}

PurchaseTable.prototype._addtoTable = function(purchasedItem){

var itemHtml = '<tr><td>' + purchasedItem.subTotal +'</td></tr>';//construct the layout of the purchased Item with all the data in here

this.containerElement.find('#tableBody').prepend(itemHtml);
this.containerElement.find('#total').html(this.totalAmount);
}

PurchaseTable.prototype._initializeTableLayout = function(){

var tableHtml = "<table><thead><tr><th>Column1</th></tr></thead><tbody id='tableBody'><tr><td id='total'>0</td></tr></tbody></table>";//PLace HTML of table with headers and empty table body in here

this.containerElement.html(tableHtml);

}

</script>

<script>

var purchases = null;

function initPurchases(){

purchases = new PurchaseTable('container');
}

function addItem(){

purchases.addItem({id:1, subTotal:10});

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initPurchases();">

<div id="container"></div>
<button onclick="addItem();">Add Item</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function loadgrandtotal()
             {

              var prodprice=0;
                 $('#tablebody tr').each(function() {
                    prodprice =prodprice + Number($(this).find(".subtot").text()).toFixed(2);  

                 });

             }
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? It won't work, due to the fact you are adding strings (`toFixed`) and not numbers.

Answer (score -2):

That's because `$('#tSortable_2 tbody tr').each` is executed once and not dynamically. That means, it's only executed when the `loadgrandtotal` is called and not every time you create a new row. Instead, you need to make sure the new rows are included every that function is run. To do that, you need to make sure `loadgrandtotal` is in some way run more than once (I would do that by running it whenever the price is added).

```
$('.priceInput').on('change', loadgrandtotal);
```

N.B: Be careful with doing decimal calculations. It's much butter to convert your prices to integers and later on convert them to decimal.

Comment: `loadgrandtotal` *is* called more than once, it is called each time a new row is added, as shown in the code in the question. Also, where are you seeing the `priceInput` class being used?